# How to configure Apache Airflow start_date and schedule_interval to run daily at 7am?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm using Airflow airflow-2.3.3 (through GCP Composer)

I pass this yaml configuration when deploying my DAG:

```
 dag_args:
  dag_id: FTP_DAILY
  default_args:
    owner: 'Dev team'
    start_date: "00:00:00"
    max_active_runs: 1
    retries: 2
  schedule_interval: "0 7 * * *"
  ftp_conn_id: 'ftp_dev'
```

I want this DAG to run at 7am UTC every morning, but it's not running. In the UI it says next run: `2022-11-22, 07:00:00` (as of Nov 22nd)  and it never runs. How should I configure my `start_date` and `schedule_interval` so that the DAG runs at 7am UTC every day, starting from the nearest 7am after the deployment?

Comment: Can you add default args in `Python` directly in the DAG ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass default args directly in the `Python` DAG code and calculate yesterday's date, example :

```py
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

dag_default_args = {
   'depends_on_past': False,
   'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
   'email_on_failure': False,
   'email_on_retry': False,
   'retries': 0,
   'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
   'start_date': days_ago(1)
}
```

Then in the DAG :

```py
with airflow.DAG(
        "dag_name",
        default_args=dag_default_args,
        schedule_interval="0 7 * * *") as dag:
......
```

In this case the `schedule_interval` and `cron` will work correctly, `Airflow` will based the cron DAG on the start date.

Answer (score 1):

The main concept of airflow is that the execution of a dag starts after the required interval has [passed](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.3/faq.html#:%7E:text=Is%20your%20start_date%20set%20properly%3F%20The%20Airflow%20scheduler%20triggers%20the%20task%20soon%20after%20the%20start_date%20%2B%20schedule_interval%20is%20passed.). If you schedule a dag with the above setup airflow will parse
**interval_start_date as 2022-11-22 07:00:00**
and **interval_end_date as 2022-11-23 07:00:00**
As you are requesting airflow to fetch data from this interval it will wait for the interval to pass, thus starting execution on 23rd November 7am.
If you want it to trigger immediately after you deploy the dag you need to move the start date back by one day. You might need to set up the catchup flag to [true](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.3/dag-run.html#:%7E:text=in%20DAG%20or%20catchup_by_default%C2%A0%3D%C2%A0False%20in%20the%20configuration%20file.%20When%20turned%20off%2C%20the%20scheduler%20creates%20a%20DAG%20run%20only%20for%20the%20latest).

```
with DAG(
dag_id='new_workflow4',
schedule_interval="0 7 * * *",
start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 11, 21, hour=0, tz="UTC"),
catchup=True
) as dag:
```